# Using tw-elements in a Hugo site

Tags: tailwind-css, hugo

I want to add a carousel in a Hugo site, so I'm trying to use tw-elements. I have used their [quick start guide](https://tailwind-elements.com/quick-start/) and put the tw-elements plugin in the plugins section of the tailwind-config.js file, but the script isn't exported to the public folder. Has anyone done this before? What step(s) am I missing?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just putting the `tailwind-config.js` file in Hugo won't be enough. You need to:

1. generate a `style.css` using Tailwind in your `assets/` or `static/` directory
2. put a link to the `style.css` generated by Tailwind into Hugo, for example in `<head></head>` section, for example in the baseof.html template.

See here for a complete guide on integrating Hugo with Tailwind:
https://www.unsungnovelty.org/posts/03/2022/how-to-add-tailwind-css-3-to-a-hugo-website-in-2022/

An alternative is to use Tailwind CDN by putting the following line in the `<head></head>` section of your site:

```
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
```